# Specs of HK-TR6A remote controller receiver

Tags: arduino, remote-control, pinout, specifications

I'm trying to use a 2.4 GHz digital 6 channel remote controller to send signals to an Arduino UNO R3 board. The receiver is the [HK-TR6A-V2](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__12901__hobby_king_2_4ghz_receiver_6ch_v2.html).

I can't find any information on what each pin input/output is, and how the information is encoded. Since there are 3 pins for each of the 6 channels, I imagine that each channel has its own Vcc and ground, and the signal itself will be on the third pin, but I'm not sure which is which.

Also, I don't know what voltage should be supplied to the battery pins (and why there are 3 pins for the battery).

The modulation used to encode the signal in each channel seems to be PPM, but I'm also not sure about that.

Has anyone worked with this receiver (or a similar one)? Is there a manual or any information about how to interface it with an Arduino board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HK-TR6A-V2 receiver is designed to drive standard model radio control servos, which require 4.8~6V and a PWM signal that varies in width from 1~2ms at a frequency about 50Hz (20ms frame time). On this receiver the pin next to each channel label is signal, the center pin is Vcc, and the pin closest to the end of the case is Gnd. Power rails are common to all channels. A separate battery port is also provided to feed power into, in case all the channels have servos plugged into them.

At one time this receiver included a PPM signal stream, but apparently this feature has been removed in the latest units (since 2012?). If yours is an older one then it may have PPM on the 'signal' pin of the battery port (marked BATT).

Note that PPM (Pulse **Position** Modulation) and PWM (pulse **Width** Modulation) are not the same thing. PPM allows several servo channels to be encoded on a single wire. PWM is the signal sent to *one* servo. Some people also call individual servo pulses 'PPM' but that is not correct.

[How To Read RC Receiver PPM Stream](http://rcarduino.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-read-rc-receiver-ppm-stream.html)

[Decoding 6 servo channel inputs with an Arduino UNO](http://ceptimus.co.uk/?p=66)